# Flutter Parsing Nested Array Json value using conditional statements

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a csv table which I converted into a json and want to parse this json in flutter based on conditional statements.

For example, first condition would be if the type is a planet and if the name matches the provided value then show the rest of the details in a list view like Charcs, Color and Distance.

Input would be just the type and name, so based on that I need to parse the json and extract the correct data.

Either I can have like 6 separate jsons for each type but it does not seem to be a good idea to me.

Any suggestions on how I can use conditional statements or maybe convert this json into a different format so that I can parse using indexes or elements in Flutter.

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Jupiter",
    "Charcs": "Largest",
    "Color": "blue",
    "distance": "near"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Charcs": "Inhabited",
    "Color": "green",
    "distance": "nearby"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Mars",
    "Charcs": "Red Planet",
    "Color": "red",
    "distance": "very near"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Polaris",
    "Charcs": "abcddw",
    "Color": "casc",
    "distance": "far"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Sirius",
    "Charcs": "qwqwd",
    "Color": "asfaf",
    "distance": "very far"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Betelgeuse",
    "Charcs": "qwdwqeq",
    "Color": "asfasfa",
    "distance": "far far away"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is an array, you can use a loop that filters each item into a separate JSON key.

```js
var array = [
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Jupiter",
    "Charcs": "Largest",
    "Color": "blue",
    "distance": "near"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Earth",
    "Charcs": "Inhabited",
    "Color": "green",
    "distance": "nearby"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Planet",
    "Name": "Mars",
    "Charcs": "Red Planet",
    "Color": "red",
    "distance": "very near"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Polaris",
    "Charcs": "abcddw",
    "Color": "casc",
    "distance": "far"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Sirius",
    "Charcs": "qwqwd",
    "Color": "asfaf",
    "distance": "very far"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Star",
    "Name": "Betelgeuse",
    "Charcs": "qwdwqeq",
    "Color": "asfasfa",
    "distance": "far far away"
  }
]

var json = {}
array.forEach(e => {
  json[e.Type] ||= {}
  json[e.Type][e.Name] = {Charcs: e.Charcs,Color: e.Color,distance:e.distance}
})
console.log(json)
```

The definition of the code above is the following:

1. `json[e.Type] ||= {}`: This creates a key from the object type if it does not already exist
2. `json[e.Type][e.Name] = {Charcs: e.Charcs,Color: e.Color,distance:e.distance}`: This puts the data of the object in its own sub-key

Comment: Or, if you want the data to be an array instead of json, just replace `{Charcs: e.Charcs,Color: e.Color,distance:e.distance}` with `[e.Charcs,e.Color,e.distance]`.